# Display javascript variable value with html tags

Tags: javascript

How can I display the value from a variable in javascript, using javascript in  tag for example?
Here is my code so far:

```
var a = 5;
$("#htmlId").html(a+'<h3> days left</h3>');
```

I want to use the variable a inside the  tag. How can I do it?

Comment: You mean like this `$("#htmlId").html('<h3> ' + a + ' days left</h3>');`

Comment: yes, that is he answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple string concatenation:

```
$("#htmlId").html('<h3>' + a + ' days left</h3>');
```